# Fill table from left to right using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am generating a PDF using iTextSharp.dll in C#.net.

**Requirement:**

I am in need of creating a PDF of Directory with information. My PDF Document contains the following sections in a **single page**:

1. Header (Banner Image)
2. Title (As Directory)
3. Contents (Contains directory information)

   3.1. Left side contents

   3.2. Right side contents
4. Footer (Contains page number)

Below is the picture or layout of how the document will look like:[image]

*From the above, Header, Title and Footer will be same for all the pages.*

**Detailed explanation about content table section:**

Content table section holds the people information. We have the following type of information to be filled.

1. Image
2. Person Details with address.

The process of filling the information is as follows:

1. First fill the Images and Person Details in the ***Left Content Table***.
2. While adding the content, if the ***left content table*** reaches the footer or if it exceeds the footer of a page, then move to the ***Right Content Table***
3. On filling the ***right content table***, if it exceeds the footer, then move on to the next page and proceed with the ***left content table*** of the new page.

**What I tried:**

I tried to complete this approach for a single page.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ///// ---- Table creation in PDF using iTextSharp -----///



        /// Creating a document
        ///
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

        if (File.Exists("F:\\Output.pdf"))
            File.Delete("F:\\Output.pdf");
        FileStream pdfFileStream = new FileStream("F:\\Output.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        string bannerPath = "F:\\banner.png";
        iTextSharp.text.Image bannerImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bannerPath);
        bannerImage.ScaleToFit(50f, 90f);
        using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, pdfFileStream))
        {

            document.Open();
            PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.DirectContent;


            ///// ---- Table creation in PDF using iTextSharp -----///

            PdfPTable documentTable = new PdfPTable(1);

            documentTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            documentTable.TotalWidth = 570;
            documentTable.LockedWidth = true;
            documentTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            documentTable.SplitLate = false;
            documentTable.SplitRows = true;
            //firstRowTable first column

            //Header name table
            PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
            documentTable.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            headerTable.TotalWidth = 570;
            headerTable.LockedWidth = true;
            headerTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            //Add Image to the cell with auto fit true.
            PdfPCell headerCell = new PdfPCell(bannerImage);
            headerTable.AddCell(headerCell);
            documentTable.AddCell(headerTable);


            PdfPTable titleTable = new PdfPTable(1);
            titleTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            titleTable.TotalWidth = 200;
            titleTable.LockedWidth = true;

            //Title.
            Phrase titlePhrase = new Phrase();
            var FontColour = new BaseColor(31, 73, 125);
            var normalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 15, FontColour);
            Chunk titleChunk = new Chunk("Physician Directory", normalFont);
            titlePhrase.Add(titleChunk);
            PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(titlePhrase);
            cell1.Border = 0;//No border
            titleTable.AddCell(cell1);

            documentTable.AddCell(titleTable);

            #region "Physician's table"

            //Create Physician table.
            PdfPTable physicianTable = new PdfPTable(2);
            physicianTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            physicianTable.TotalWidth = 570;
            physicianTable.LockedWidth = true;
            physicianTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            #region "Physician's left side table"

            //Create Physician table.
            PdfPTable physicianLeftTable = new PdfPTable(2);
            physicianLeftTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            physicianLeftTable.TotalWidth = 285;
            physicianLeftTable.LockedWidth = true;
            physicianLeftTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            #region "Physician's left side table contents 1"

            #region "Physician's column1"

            string doctor1Path = "F:\\Doctor1.jpg";
            iTextSharp.text.Image doctor1Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(doctor1Path);
            doctor1Image.ScaleToFit(50f, 90f);
            PdfPCell physicianLeftTableContent1Column1 = new PdfPCell(doctor1Image);

            physicianLeftTableContent1Column1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            physicianLeftTable.AddCell(physicianLeftTableContent1Column1);
            #endregion "Physician's column1"

            #region "Physician's column2"
            Phrase paraPhrase = new Phrase();
            var nameChunkFontColour = new BaseColor(31, 73, 125);
            var nameChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8, nameChunkFontColour);
            Chunk nameChunk = new Chunk("Name1\n", nameChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(nameChunk));

            var doctorType1ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 8);
            Chunk doctorType1Chunk = new Chunk("Pediatric Neurologist,\n", doctorType1ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(doctorType1Chunk));

            var doctorType2ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 8);
            Chunk doctorType2Chunk = new Chunk("Headache Medicine\n", doctorType1ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(doctorType2Chunk));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            var healthGroupChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk healthGroupChunk = new Chunk("Health Medical Group\n", healthGroupChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(healthGroupChunk));

            var addressLine1ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine1Chunk = new Chunk("Pediatric Neurology, \n", addressLine1ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine1Chunk));

            var addressLine2ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine2Chunk = new Chunk("701 Road\n", addressLine2ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine2Chunk));

            var addressLine3ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine3Chunk = new Chunk("Village, IL 7\n", addressLine3ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine3Chunk));

            var zipCodeChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
            Chunk zipCodeChunk = new Chunk("123-456 -789\n", zipCodeChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(zipCodeChunk));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            var healthGroup1ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk healthGroup1Chunk = new Chunk("Health Medical Group\n", healthGroup1ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(healthGroup1Chunk));

            var addressLine1ChunkNormalFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine1Chunk1 = new Chunk("Pediatric Neurology, \n", addressLine1ChunkNormalFont1);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine1Chunk1));

            var addressLine2ChunkNormalFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine2Chunk1 = new Chunk("701 Road\n", addressLine2ChunkNormalFont1);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine2Chunk1));

            var addressLine3ChunkNormalFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine3Chunk1 = new Chunk("Village, IL 7\n", addressLine3ChunkNormalFont1);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine3Chunk1));

            var zipCodeChunkNormalFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
            Chunk zipCodeChunk1 = new Chunk("123-456 -7890\n", zipCodeChunkNormalFont1);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(zipCodeChunk1));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            var healthGroup2ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk healthGroup2Chunk = new Chunk("Health Medical Group\n", healthGroup2ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(healthGroup2Chunk));

            var addressLine1ChunkNormalFont2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine1Chunk2 = new Chunk("Pediatric Neurology\n", addressLine1ChunkNormalFont2);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine1Chunk2));

            var addressLine2ChunkNormalFont2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine2Chunk2 = new Chunk("701 Road\n", addressLine2ChunkNormalFont2);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine2Chunk2));

            var addressLine3ChunkNormalFont2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine3Chunk2 = new Chunk("Village, IL 12345\n", addressLine3ChunkNormalFont2);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine3Chunk2));

            var zipCodeChunkNormalFont2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
            Chunk zipCodeChunk2 = new Chunk("123-456 -7890\n", zipCodeChunkNormalFont2);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(zipCodeChunk2));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            var healthGroup3ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk healthGroup3Chunk = new Chunk("Health Medical Group\n", healthGroup3ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(healthGroup3Chunk));

            var addressLine1ChunkNormalFont3 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine1Chunk3 = new Chunk("Pediatric Neurology\n", addressLine1ChunkNormalFont3);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine1Chunk3));

            var addressLine2ChunkNormalFont3 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine2Chunk3 = new Chunk("701 Road\n", addressLine2ChunkNormalFont3);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine2Chunk3));

            var addressLine3ChunkNormalFont3 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine3Chunk3 = new Chunk("Village, IL 12345\n", addressLine3ChunkNormalFont3);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine3Chunk3));

            var zipCodeChunkNormalFont3 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
            Chunk zipCodeChunk3 = new Chunk("123-456 -7890\n", zipCodeChunkNormalFont3);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(zipCodeChunk3));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            var healthGroup4ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk healthGroup4Chunk = new Chunk("Health Medical Group\n", healthGroup4ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(healthGroup4Chunk));

            var addressLine1ChunkNormalFont4 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine1Chunk4 = new Chunk("Pediatric Neurology\n", addressLine1ChunkNormalFont4);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine1Chunk4));

            var addressLine2ChunkNormalFont4 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine2Chunk4 = new Chunk("Road\n", addressLine2ChunkNormalFont4);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine2Chunk4));

            var addressLine3ChunkNormalFont4 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine3Chunk4 = new Chunk("Village, IL 12345\n", addressLine3ChunkNormalFont4);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine3Chunk4));

            var zipCodeChunkNormalFont4 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
            Chunk zipCodeChunk4 = new Chunk("123-456 -7890\n", zipCodeChunkNormalFont4);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(zipCodeChunk4));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            PdfPCell physicianLeftTableContent1Column2 = new PdfPCell(paraPhrase);
            physicianLeftTableContent1Column2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            physicianLeftTable.AddCell(physicianLeftTableContent1Column2);

            int count = pdfWriter.PageNumber;

            #endregion "Physician's column2"

            //physicianLeftTable.AddCell(physicianLeftTableContent1);

            #endregion "Physician's left side content table"

            #region "Physician's left side table contents 2"
            //Create left side table.
            PdfPTable physicianLeftTableContent2 = new PdfPTable(2);
            physicianLeftTableContent2.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            physicianLeftTableContent2.TotalWidth = 142.5f;
            physicianLeftTableContent2.LockedWidth = true;
            physicianLeftTableContent2.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            #region "Physician's column1"

            string doctor2Path = "F:\\Image2.jpg";
            iTextSharp.text.Image doctor2Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(doctor2Path);
            doctor2Image.ScaleToFit(50f, 90f);
            PdfPCell physicianLeftTableContent2Column1 = new PdfPCell(doctor2Image);

            physicianLeftTableContent2Column1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            physicianLeftTable.AddCell(physicianLeftTableContent2Column1);

            #endregion "Physician's column1"

            #region "Physician's column2"
            Phrase paraPhrase1 = new Phrase();
            var nameChunkFontColour1 = new BaseColor(31, 73, 125);
            var nameChunkNormalFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8, nameChunkFontColour1);
            Chunk nameChunk1 = new Chunk("Name1 M.D.\n", nameChunkNormalFont1);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(nameChunk1));

            var doctorType3ChunkNormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 8);
            Chunk doctorType3Chunk = new Chunk("General Surgery\n", doctorType3ChunkNormalFont);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(doctorType3Chunk));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            var healthGroupChunkNormalFont5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk healthGroupChunk5 = new Chunk("Medical Center\n", healthGroupChunkNormalFont5);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(healthGroupChunk5));

            var addressLine1ChunkNormalFont5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine1Chunk5 = new Chunk("First Avenue\n", addressLine1ChunkNormalFont5);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine1Chunk5));

            var addressLine2ChunkNormalFont5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine2Chunk5 = new Chunk("Room 3230\n", addressLine2ChunkNormalFont5);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine2Chunk5));

            var addressLine3ChunkNormalFont5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine3Chunk5 = new Chunk("IL 60153\n", addressLine3ChunkNormalFont5);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine3Chunk5));

            var zipCodeChunkNormalFont5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
            Chunk zipCodeChunk5 = new Chunk("123-456 -7890\n", zipCodeChunkNormalFont5);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(zipCodeChunk5));

            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            var healthGroupChunkNormalFont6 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk healthGroupChunk6 = new Chunk("Medical Center\n", healthGroupChunkNormalFont6);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(healthGroupChunk6));

            var addressLine1ChunkNormalFont6 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine1Chunk6 = new Chunk("First Avenue\n", addressLine1ChunkNormalFont6);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine1Chunk6));

            var addressLine2ChunkNormalFont6 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine2Chunk6 = new Chunk("Room 3230\n", addressLine2ChunkNormalFont6);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine2Chunk6));

            var addressLine3ChunkNormalFont6 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8);
            Chunk addressLine3Chunk6 = new Chunk("IL 60153\n", addressLine3ChunkNormalFont6);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(addressLine3Chunk6));

            var zipCodeChunkNormalFont6 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
            Chunk zipCodeChunk6 = new Chunk("123-456 -7890\n", zipCodeChunkNormalFont6);
            paraPhrase.Add(new Paragraph(zipCodeChunk6));


            PdfPCell physicianLeftTableContent2Column2 = new PdfPCell(paraPhrase);
            physicianLeftTableContent2Column2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            physicianLeftTable.AddCell(physicianLeftTableContent2Column2);

            #endregion "Physician's column2"

            //physicianLeftTable.AddCell(physicianLeftTableContent2);

            #endregion "Physician's left side content table"

            int count1 = pdfWriter.PageNumber;
            //Add the left side physician table.
            physicianTable.AddCell(physicianLeftTable);

            #endregion "Physician's left side table"

            #region "Physician's right side table"

            //Create Physician table.
            PdfPTable physicianRightTable = new PdfPTable(2);
            physicianRightTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            physicianRightTable.TotalWidth = 285;
            physicianRightTable.LockedWidth = true;
            physicianRightTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            #region "Physician's right side table contents 1"

            //Create right side table content.
            PdfPTable physicianRightTableContent1 = new PdfPTable(2);
            physicianRightTableContent1.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            physicianRightTableContent1.TotalWidth = 142.5f;
            physicianRightTableContent1.LockedWidth = true;
            physicianRightTableContent1.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            #region "Physician's column1"

            string doctor3Path = "F:\\Image2.jpg";
            iTextSharp.text.Image doctor3Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(doctor3Path);
            doctor3Image.ScaleToFit(50f, 90f);
            PdfPCell physicianRightTableContent1Column1 = new PdfPCell(doctor3Image);

            physicianRightTableContent1Column1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            physicianRightTable.AddCell(physicianRightTableContent1Column1);
            #endregion "Physician's column1"

            //Add the right side physician table.
            //physicianRightTable.AddCell(physicianRightTableContent1);

            #endregion "Physician's right side table contents"

            #region "Physician's right side table contents 2"

            //Create right side table content.
            PdfPTable physicianRightTableContent2 = new PdfPTable(2);
            physicianRightTableContent2.HorizontalAlignment = 0;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            physicianRightTableContent2.TotalWidth = 142.5f;
            physicianRightTableContent2.LockedWidth = true;
            physicianRightTableContent2.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            #region "Physician's column1"

            string doctor4Path = "F:\\Image1.jpg";
            iTextSharp.text.Image doctor4Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(doctor4Path);
            doctor4Image.ScaleToFit(50f, 90f);
            PdfPCell physicianRightTableContent2Column1 = new PdfPCell(doctor3Image);

            physicianRightTableContent1Column1.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            physicianRightTableContent1.AddCell(physicianRightTableContent2Column1);
            #endregion "Physician's column1"

            //Add the left side physician table.
            physicianRightTable.AddCell(physicianRightTableContent2);

            //Add the right side physician table.
            //physicianRightTable.AddCell(new Phrase("Hi"));

            #endregion "Physician's right side table contents 2"

            //Add the left side physician table.
            physicianTable.AddCell(physicianRightTable);

            #endregion "Physician's right side table"

            //Add physician table to the document table.
            documentTable.AddCell(physicianTable);

            #endregion "Physician's table"

            document.Add(documentTable);

            document.Close();
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Completed");

        //if (File.Exists("F:\\Output.pdf"))
        //    File.Open("F:\\Output.pdf", FileMode.Open);
    }

}
```

**What I need:**

1. Move the contents to the **Right Content Table** if **Left Content Table** reaches the end of the document.
2. Move the content to the next page if the **Right Content Table** reaches the end of the document and starts writing contents in the **Left Content Table** of the new page.

**NOTE:**

*Since I have no footer setup in the above code, I am trying to find the End of the document. I am stuck with finding whether the Content Table reaches the End of the document or not.*